# Got error "unknown keyword: version" when encode data using ruby gem avro turf with schema registry

Tags: ruby, avro

I have used Ruby gem `avro_turf` to convert data to binary and publish it to Kafka. But I got an error `unknown keyword: version` when try to encode data.
I have started Confluent Schema Registry on `localhost:8081`. I can create and read subject on terminal.

I scan its [source code](https://github.com/dasch/avro_turf/blob/master/lib/avro_turf/messaging.rb), there is a "version" param in encode function.

I curl `curl -X GET http://127.0.0.1:8081/subjects/avro-test/versions/1` to Schema Registry and get this data

```
{"subject":"avro-test","version":1,"id":1,"schema":"{\"type\":\"record\",\"name\":\"evolution\",\"namespace\":\"com.landoop\",\"doc\":\"This is a sample Avro schema to get you started. Please edit\",\"fields\":[{\"name\":\"name\",\"type\":\"string\"},{\"name\":\"phone\",\"type\":\"string\"},{\"name\":\"email\",\"type\":\"string\"}]}"}
```

This is my current code

```
require "avro_turf/messaging"

avro = AvroTurf::Messaging.new(registry_url: "http://localhost:8081/")

data = avro.encode('{ "name" => "hello, world", "phone": "01232323", "email": "hello@gmail.com" }', subject: 'avro-test', version: 1)
```

Please help me for solution.

Comment: There is this keyword now in current master, but is it there in the version _you're using_? Crack it open with `bundle open avro_turf` and see.

Comment: you're right, there is no "version" param in the version I am using. But I install the latest version 0.8.1, why it is different from the one on github. I removed "version" param from my code and got another error "undefined method `include?' for nil:NilClass"

Comment: What you're seeing on github is current state of development. May include not-yet-released changes (as we're seeing here). Here's code for [v0.8.1](https://github.com/dasch/avro_turf/blob/v0.8.1/lib/avro_turf/messaging.rb)

Comment: You can use the latest and greatest by using the gem like this: `gem "avro_turf", github: "dasch/avro_turf"`. Beware of instability and bugs.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion and advice, I will consider it. Thanks a lot

Comment: I'm going to post an answer, to earn some internet points :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I scan its source code, there is a "version" param in encode function.

Yes, the problem is, you're looking at the current state of `master` branch. As of now, it contains unreleased changes, this keyword included.

So either wait for next version to be released, or use master directly

```
gem "avro_turf", github: "dasch/avro_turf"
```